# Typescript compiler never Error: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Here is a piece of code i got:

```js
interface Obj {
  a: number
  b: string
}

const obj: Obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'hi'
}

function fn(key: keyof Obj, value: Obj[keyof Obj]) {
  let foo = obj[key]
  obj[key] = value
}

fn("a", 2)
```

So what i want to do is, i want the function `fn()` to be able to update the object `obj` properties, the first argument of this function is any key that `obj` has(defined in `Obj` interface), and the second argument is the value you wanna give to that key.

However, the typescript popup with an error in the `obj[key] = value` this line, which is:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: error message]

And a strange thing happens here, if you hover to the variable `foo`(which is line 13 in the picture), it says:

```
let foo: string | number
```

which means, `obj[key]`'s type is `string | number`, but the error says `obj[key]` type is `never`.

> **so my first question is: How come a `string | number` type magically becomes a never type? Is there any way to fix this?**

Then i got another piece of code which solves this problem:

```js
interface Obj {
  a: number
  b: string
}

const obj: Obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'hi'
}

function fn<K extends keyof Obj>(key: K, value: Obj[K]) {
  obj[key] = value
}

fn("a", 2)
```

> **Therefore my second question would be: why using `Generics` solve the problem and what the hack is the keyword `extends` here?**

BTW, all the code are tested in typescript `3.7.5` version.

I am not a native English speaker, hope i explained my confusion clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the error, it's because `keyof Obj` might be `"a"` or `"b"` which have type `number` or `string`. In the expression `obj[key]` the compiler doesn't know the property type, it might be `number` or `string` as well, so it disallows such assignment. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31663) is the same question. And you can find the explanation [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/), see *Fixes to unsound writes to indexed access types*.

In case of the generic function `K extends keyof Obj` means that `K` type can be `"a"` or `"b"` as well, but when you call the function `fn("a", 2)` you implicitly set `K` to `"a"`, the compiler infers `K` type from the first argument. So now, inside the call context `key` has `"a"` type and `Obj[K]` is `number`, hence the assignment becomes correct.

---

I just tried to explain the difference to my wife, who isn't a programmer :) I think it might be helpfull too:

> *Usual function:* Lets imagine you are eating a cake but your eyes are closed. You know that it might be a cherry cake or a banana cake. You like the taste but you cannot say "What a delicious banana cake!" because you are not sure that it's a banana cake.
>
> *Generic function:* In this case you eyes are open and you can choose the cake you want to eat, but you still have two choices: cherry or banana. Now, if you've chosen the banana cake and tasted it, you can say "What a delicious banana cake!".

Comment: Thanks for you explanation, however i just got one stupid question, as you said: "you implicitly set K to a", but why can't `keyof Obj` do the same? why can't implicitly set `keyof Obj` to 'a' as well? What really happens under the hood?

Comment: @Limboer Generics allow you to specify a type when you call a function. A usual function argument types are constant, like `keyof Obj` in your case. In case of the generic function you tell the compiler that the function accepts an argument of type `K` and the type should satisfy the constraint `extends keyof Obj`, in other words it must be `"a"` or `"b"`. When you call the function you specify the type explicitly like `fn<"a">("a", 2)` or it can be implicitly inferred from the arguments you pass to the function, but now it's not the union type `"a" | "b"` but just `"a"`. I hope it'll help you

Comment: @Limboer I've also added a real life explanation to the answer, I hope it might be helpful too