# Type error when trying to assign to object copy

Tags: typescript

Can anyone tell my why I'm receiving:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

When I try to assign value to object copied by JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) object.

Here's my code:

```
interface X { 
    a: number
    b: string
}

const one: X = {
    a:1, b:'1'
}

let d:X = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(one)) as X

const ke = Object.keys(d) as Array<keyof X>

ke.forEach(key => {
    let nn = d[key];
    nn = one[key];
    d[key] = nn;
})
```

also playground link: [TS-Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN7IFDL8uALmRAFcBbAI2l30uIGcwpQBzbAX22wQHsQmyfhGLoAvJlp4iARgA0yegHIZSztwA2EMMgAmhccgBSAZQDyAOQB0ABzhQGEABSnLVpixCtgMAJ5PhAEpAggY0bj4BHQBrFAkzSgArCAQwK1jfBiddELgwgEEoKDhfAB4M3hg0AD5uWKsYXigAUUQACycM5DFqyXxkLR0QEG69AG0MgF0AbikSEYlhCYhfGbndZdXR4dmOQKA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript compiler never Error: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000835/typescript-compiler-never-error-type-string-number-is-not-assignable-to-typ)

Comment: Because key is of type string | number while d only accepts "a" or "b" as keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TypeScript 3.5 started to [warn on possibly unsafe index access writes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types), this has been a pain point.  In TypeScript 3.4 and below this would have been acceptable code since it would have been interpreting as assigning `string | number` to `string | number`; the downside is that it would also have been acceptable to write `d[key] = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "str" : 123;`, which is clearly wrong.

In TypeScript 3.5 and above the compiler is now overly strict in cases like this; it insists that you can only assign something which is both a `string` *and* a `number` to `d[key]` since it isn't sure which element of `keyof X` the `key` is.  Since there *are* no values of type `string & number`, the type is reduced to `never`.  So it's impossible to safely assign any value to `d[key]` according to the compiler.

There's an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693), asking to allow such assignments, in the case where [the key is the *exactly the same*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693#issuecomment-598860475) in both the read and the write, and not just the same type (since two values of type `keyof X` could be different keys, but two references to the same value of type `keyof X` cannot).  This hasn't been implemented yet, though.  If you want to see it implemented, you might want to go to that issue and give it a .  In the meantime, we have to work around it.

---

One workaround here (other than using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) which is always an option, or writing redundant code as in the other answer) is to make your callback function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the type of `key`:

```
ke.forEach(<K extends keyof X>(key: K) => {
    let nn = d[key];
    nn = one[key];
    d[key] = nn;
})
```

There is no error there because the compiler does allow reads and writes to values of *identical* types, and when you have `K` as an unresolved generic, the compiler thinks that `X[K]` on the read is the same as the `X[K]` on the write.  (I got this from [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559), which is explained by the chief architect of TS).

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4Chm+XALmRAFcBbAI2hzwqIGcwpQBzLAXyywQHsRHkfCEXQBeTDVyFkARgA0yOsgDkM5Ry4AbCGGQATEcnEApAMoB5AHIA6AA5wo9CAAozV642YgWwGAE9nIQBKIPx6NC5efl0AaxRxcwoAKwgEMGs4v3pnPVC4cIBBKCg4PwAeTJ4YNAA+LjjrGB4oAFFEAAtnMoBpZAgAD0gQPXDK6tQa50yibtDRGok8ZG1dEBAjfQBtTIBdAG5JYnXxIW2IP33DvTOLjYBZODB26xLhnjJnULLkAAZrAFZkAB+ZAAIk8oOQRBkACYAMx7ZAAeiRfWKzSuNx2GzWB3YQSAA)

Comment: I like your elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

This operation:

```
d[key] = nn;
```

is (correctly) rejected by the type-checker. Because neither `key` nor `nn` are known in advance, there is a possibility that the wrong value will be assigned to the wrong property.

`key` is `"a" | "b"`. This means that `d[key]` should be either `string | number`, depending on whether `key` is `"a"` or `"b"`. You can't assign a `string` to `"a"` and a number to `"b"` — because that wouldn't be an `X` anymore.

So, we have two degrees of freedom with two options for each. This leaves us with 4 possible scenarios, out of which only two are valid.

A solution would be to ensure we're dealing with one of the correct combinations:

```
ke.forEach(key => {
    let nn = d[key];
    nn = one[key];

    if (key === 'a' && typeof nn === 'number') {
        d[key] = nn;
    }

    if (key === 'b' && typeof nn === 'string') {
        d[key] = nn;
    }
})
```

Comment: The compiler rejects the assignment, but not "correctly". There are only 2 possibilities, but the compiler sees 4 because it forgets that the type of `nn` is *correlated* with the type of `d[key]`. Note that `if (key === "a") { let nn = d[key]; nn = one[key]; } else { let nn = d[key]; nn = one[key]; }` compiles, so the check of `key === "a"` doesn't make anything safer; it just forces the compiler to perform control flow analysis.

Comment: This treatment of correlated union types as uncorrelated is a general problem with TS, without an obvious fix.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more about such correlated union types.  I had originally suggested [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) to allow developers to opt in to control flow analysis that treats `let nn = d[key]; nn = one[key]` *as if* you wrote the above `if/else` statement, but it was declined. So for now we just have to work around it. 